# Listview does not refresh itself after deleting item by long click?

Tags: android

I populated listview using custom SimpleCursorAdapter. Upon listview's onItemClickListener it opens another activity, its working. Now onitemLongClickListener i want to show an Alert Dialog box with Yes, No choice to delete file. Upon selecting yes, i get cursor and get item's relating database entry and remove that entry and also delete file from application data directory but listview does not refresh itself until i close app and reopen it. I tried to use adapter.changeCursor(cursor) after deleting file and db entry in longclick listener but no success. What do i need to do to make it refresh itself immediately after deleting file and db entry?

MainActivity:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
            cursor = (Cursor) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            filepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("filename"));
            final File file = new File(filepath);
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete File");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
                    int count = db.delteSingleEntry(filepath);
                    if (isDeleted && count != 0){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File deleted and Database entry removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the data observers and any ui such as listview or recyclerview to refresh itself when the underlying data is changed, this can be done by using
`BaseAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()` method.

As cursor Adapter is subclass of BaseAdapter you can use this method for your adapter as well.

[BaseAdapter documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: random aspirer, I tried to put adapter.notifydatasetchanged() after alert.show() and after if (isDeleted && count != 0){ but it is not working. Watch my code please and tell me Where should i put my adapter.notifydatasetchanged() statement?

Comment: I got it working. I called my populatelistview() method after delete statement and it updated listview immedietly. Thanx random aspirer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

but for better performance try to work with Recyclerview instance

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I called my populatelistview() method after delete statement and it updated listview immedietly. Thanx to all.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
            cursor = (Cursor) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            filepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("filename"));
            final File file = new File(filepath);
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete File");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
                    int count = db.delteSingleEntry(filepath);
                    if (isDeleted && count != 0){
                        populateListview();    //I added this line and problem resolved.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File deleted and Database entry removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

    });
```